# Are all apps published as framework-dependent cross-platform?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/#publish-framework-dependent

> Apps published as framework-dependent are cross-platform

In .net core, there are 2 modes to publish: self contained and framework dependant.

Not all framework dependant deployments are cross platform. So is the above quote wrong?

To confuse things further it says:

> Publishing an app as framework-dependent produces a cross-platform
> binary as a dll file, and a platform-specific executable that targets
> your current platform.

Answer (score 0):

The phrase is further explained above in the same page, right in the introduction to the topic:

> Both publishing modes produce a platform-specific executable by default. Framework-dependent applications can be created without an executable, and these applications are cross-platform.

It means that a "Framework-dependend" program can be deployed not by a normal .exe file, but can be compiled to a IL-only binary (often a .dll file) that's run on the target machine by the `dotnet` executable (that's the framework dependency). Since you run the very same dll not by executing it directly but by running its IL though the interpreter in the Framework, the very same binary runs unmodified on any system that can run the .NET Core runtime. That's what they call "cross-platform".

Of course, that doesn't means that each and every program made this way is cross-platform. What your code does must also avoid any platform-specific calls and libraries like always, or those that you do use must also be cross-platform.
This is what most developers call "cross-platform".

Comment: So is the quote from my question wrong. I'm asking so that a pull request can be made to fix it if it's wrong.

Comment: Most likely yes, probably requiring clarification of what the mean by "cross platform".

Comment: So, only the framework dependant binary is cross platform right?

Comment: Next it says `Publishing an app as framework-dependent produces a cross-platform binary as a dll file, and a platform-specific executable that targets your current platform.` - I can't see how this release is cross platform when it still has an executable.

Comment: It generates both, but only one of them is actually needed to run the program. Which you use depends on what system you intend to deploy.

Comment: You have a point but that's valid only if a particular platform isn't targeted when making the release. In this case it still produces the executable and dll, but this isn't really cross platform.